# Code Igniter Session not geting any value at index page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm new at Code Igniter. My index page is named abc_welcome where i've below code

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $login_data = $this->session->userdata('user');

    if($login_data) {
        redirect('/product/product_details');
    }
    else {
                $this->display();
    }
}
```

So when a already logged in user hit he can redirect to product page. But strangely it is not redirecting.

Where as at login page i've same piece of code and it is redirecting all right.

So when a user come to my www.abc.com page it's not redirecting (if loged in) and session has no data checked but when cliking login button he is and obviously session got the right data. i want him to redirect first time.... more strangely in my demo site (my laptop) Index redirecting is working!!! but not at hostgator.com.

Thanks in advance.
Farness

Comment: can u echo something in `if` and `else` condition and see what is echoing

Comment: echoing $login_data do not show anything.....

now another strange thing please don't think i'm crazy.... if i put www.abc.com it is not redirecting but if i put abc.com then it's redirecting with above code....

Comment: can you tell me what you had written in config file i mean in your base_url ?

Comment: load url helper so that redirect can work

Comment: http://abc_com/
hmmm should i put http://www_abc_com.... then will it work for both www_abc_com and abc_com (please treat _ as .)

Comment: url helper is loaded at construct

    public function __construct()
  {
   parent::__construct();
          $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->library('encrypt');
   $this->load->library('session');
     } @ raheel shan

@Rakesh Shetty tried www.abc.com at base url... not working...

Comment: ok i want some information from you ....what is your controller name and what is your default controller ?? I want to know what you had written in your routes.php file `$route['default_controller'] = "";` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your support.

i finally made it work by .htaccess redirecting. i just put below code to my .htaccess and it's working as expected.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

yes @farness put `$config['base_url']   = 'http://www.abc.com/';`    in your config.php file

Comment: yaar tried that not working...if i use  'http://www[dot]abc[dot]com/';    
then www.abc.com  & abc.com both are not redirecting.

Comment: ok i want some information from you ....what is your controller name and what is your default controller ?? I want to know what you had written in your routes.php file $route['default_controller'] = ""; ??

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "welcome/abc_welcome";
controller name same as abc_welcome under welcome folder

Comment: this is correct ,tell me what is happening when you enter www.abc.com in your url ? what error you get ?

Comment: www.abc.com no error... just stayed in welcome page... if or if not the user is logged in...i wnat it redirect if logged in otherwise OK

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing, it seems like your code is fine, if it runs locally on your laptop, so it's likely that the session data isn't being stored/read properly.  Aside from the base_url above, you should also verify the following settings in /appication/config.php:

1. $config['cookie_domain'] should be set to .abc.com (with the leading dot) if your base url is www.abc.com
2. $config['cookie_path'] just to be safe, set this to "/"
3. $config['cookie_secure'] set to FALSE (unless your site is accessed only using https, keep this as false

Hopefully that gets you up and running.

Comment: I already have
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".abc.com";
$config['cookie_path']  = "/";
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;

Comment: in my laptop $config['cookie_domain']="" though.

Also if i put abc.com at address bar it is redirecting but if www.abc.com then not

Comment: whatever the domain you have running on your laptop, is what needs to be configured in the $config['cookie_domain'], and it should match your base_url variable.

Comment: hi nageeb... my laptop it is ok 
having problem on live server and there it is set as ".abc.com"

Comment: is your website actually at abc.com? it should be set to .<your_domain_name>